# Questions about Hironaka's example

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry, kahler-manifolds

In Hartshorne's book 《Algebraic geomery》 p.443, the author gives an explanation of Hironaka's example on non-Kähler deformation of compact Kähler manifolds, his construction can be summarised as follows:

Let $X$ be a complex projective manifold of dimension 3, take 2 non-singular curves $c, d\subset X$ which meet transversally at 2 points $P,Q$, and nowhere else. On $X-Q$, first blow up $c$, then the strict transform of $d$. On $X-P$, first blow up $d$, then the strict transform of $c$. Glue these two manifolds together, then we get Hironaka's example$-$a Moishezon manifold $\tilde X$ which is non-Kähler.

Regarding his construction, I have 2 questions:

1. What if we change the projective manifold $X$ to an arbitrary compact complex manifold with the blow-up process remains the same, can we still get a non-Kähler $\tilde X$ as in the projective case, or some restrictions should be added on $X$?
2. Recall that, in Hartshorne's construction, $l_0$ is the inverse image of $P$ when blow up in $c$ in $X-Q$, and $m_0'$ the inverse image of $Q$ when blow up $d$ in $X-P$, and by some algebraic equivalences, he gets the conclusion that $l_0+m_0'\sim 0$ which is impossible on a projective variety. Here comes my question: is $l_0+m_0'\sim 0$ equivalent to $l_0\sim 0$ and $m_0'\sim 0$? And either $l_0\sim 0$ or $m_0'\sim 0$ suffices to imply that $\tilde X$ is non-Kähler?

Any comment is welcome.

Comment: You are mixing the two examples given by Hartshorne. In order to get a Moishezon manifold, he just blows up one curve with a double point, and obtains indeed $l_0\sim 0$.

Comment: @abx, I know the second example of Hartshorne (blowing up one curve with a double point) is a Moishezon manifold, but his first example (blowing up 2 curves) is also a Moishezon manifold, isn't it? Otherwise we will have a counter-example of Popovici's conjecture: the limiting fiber of projective manifolds is Moishezon.

Comment: OK, you are right. Then the answer to 2. is no: if $l_0+m'_0$ implies $l_0\sim m'_0 \sim0$, you get also $l'_0\sim m_0\sim 0$, hence $l\sim l_0+m_0\sim 0$, which is false.

Comment: @abx, I think there is a misprint in Hartshorne's book p.444,  actually, it should be $l\sim l_0'$ not $l\sim l_0$, so $l_0\sim m_0'\sim 0$ only implies $l\sim m\sim m_0\sim l_0'$ which are all not $\sim 0$, thus there is no conclusion that $l\sim 0$, is that right?

Comment: Right again, there is indeed a misprint in Hartshorne. However $l\sim m$ is impossible: if $e$ is the exceptional divisor above $l$, we have $e\cdot l=-1$ but $e\cdot m=0$.

Comment: I' sorry that my background is complex geometry, so I'm not quite understand your argument  in the language of algebraic geometry, do you know how $l_0+m'_0\sim 0$ implies the non-Kähler property?

Comment: Yes, of course. If you have a Kähler metric, it is positive on any subvariety, in particular on each curve, so a curve cannot be algebraically equivalent to zero.

Comment: @abs $l_0+m'_0\sim 0$ means that $l_0+m'_0$ is the boundary of a connected submanifold or the boundary of 2 submanifolds which are not connected? If the latter, then doesn't it implies $l_0\sim m'_0 \sim0$?

Comment: No, algebraic equivalence is more complicated than what you think. In our case you can just think of $l,m,$ etc. as cohomology classes.